# Centering CSS Page - Classes conflicted

Tags: css, center

I cant center this page, no matter what. It's a simple task. Sorry Im so new to CSS.
Please help....

http://imageoneads.com/zenliver/

Comment: Absolute positioning on the menu surely won't help you center the whole thing. Also, when targetting screens with a 1024x768 resolution, don't forget to leave about 15 pixels of width to allow for scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you have styles in the main.css file and in the head of the html, I would consolidate these then

- Remove all of the 'width' from the body style (I saw multiple)
- Remove 'width' from the wrapper div (I saw multiple)
- Make sure you have the following on the wrapper div

  - width: 100%
  - margin: 0 auto;
  - clear:both;

Then on all the sub divs (header, mainContent, etc) - anything you want centered

- margin: 0 auto;
- width: 1024px

But also note that zneak is 100% correct about the 1024 width; after you get it centered then bring down the size of the header image and then update the width css as needed (might want to go as low as 980px? if you are targeting 1024)

Comment: wow, thanks so much, im thrilled to try these suggestions. You have a great weekend :)